# Migrate Blog Post to Another Website

Tags: wordpress, import, export, blogs

I am trying to migrate all my blog post from Site A to Site B.
I did the traditional way which is Tools > Export then select "Post" and Export. This one produces XML. After that, I import it via Tools > Import then Wordpress Importer. I also check the "Download and import file attachments". It imports all the content of the blog but didn't Import both Images on the content and featured Image. I can see that the URL of the images on the Site B is still "http//siteA.com/". The Featured Image is not present.

Do I want to know what other ways to transfer All Blog Post to another Site?
Is there a plugin that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a couple of plugins available for importing media file also.

I have used [Export Featured Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-featured-images/) plugin earlier for importing blog images as well and it works well.

First of all, you need to import post using default Tools-> import method of WordPress then you can use this plugin for import feature images. I have done this previously and works well.

Or this will the another plugin [WP Attachment Export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-attachment-export). This will helpful for you for importing all attachment with post content.

Hope This guide will helpful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not the complete solution, but I work like this.

1. Use [WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) plugin to export your database.
2. Change the site URL from http//siteA.com/ to http//siteB.com/
3. Uploads the wp-content folder from http//siteA.com/ to http//siteB.com/

These steps will make the clone of siteA to siteB.

> Last step will be delete the other post types and pages which you
>   don't want in siteB

Comment: I already have pages on Site B. I only need the Blog Post from Site A. I don't want to clone Site A to Site B.

Comment: The URL of the images which are wrong ("http//siteA.com/) in SiteB, are those URLs entered in Page content editor??

Comment: No. This is cause by the Export/Import of Blog Post from Site A to Site B

Answer (score 0):

The simple steps to migrate the site

1. Copy the wp-content folder
2. And export the DB also.
3. Before change in to the destination site. Please backup your site.
4. Remove the wp-content folder and paste the source wp-content files.
5. And keep a DB backup
6. drop all tables of the destination DB and import the source DB.
7. Now the last step

Go to https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

and download the folder and paste in your destination sites root folder.

Suppose Your site is example.com

run the script like example.com/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases

Change the source url to destination url as instructed in the page.

8. Now each part is same as your source file.

Comment: And if you want only posts then follow the link http://bradymower.com/how-to-move-posts-to-new-wordpress-site/. Hope this help you.

Comment: This like getting the whole content folder? I don't want other files like theme and images that are not part of the blog post cause they are so many

Comment: Then see my previous comment. that will help you.

Comment: I did check it and that is exactly what I did on the Description,

Comment: Then just download the search replace script and run as i said on the above steps. Means you have to do the 7 and 8 step.

Comment: You can't I just replace the url from Site A to Site B. The image is not imported to Site B then if I change the URL the image will return 404,

Comment: But as you said all images are imported. Or if it is not imported then, you should export again those posts. Or please use this plugin "WP Attachment Export"

Comment: I always get this error: Failed to import yst_prominent_words

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153213/discussion-between-ranjit-and-alen).